# Swift , how can I allow wkwebview playing audio when enter background

Tags: swift, audio, wkwebview

My app is using a WKwebview provide live-steam for my user.
And I would like to keep playing the audio when user enter background or switch to other app.

Do I need to open "background processing" option in project config?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to (at the least) enable background audio (look in Signing & Capabilities -> Background Modes) on your target in Xcode.